# Elegoo Mars 3 Pro USB drive formatting?

Tags: usb, elegoo-mars

I recently ran into some issues where my Mac (macOS 12.6) was no longer recognizing the USB drive that came with my Elegoo Mars 3 Pro. The printer also wouldn't recognize the drive, so I used Disk Utility to reformat the drive to MS-DOS (FAT). However, after doing this, the printer still would not recognize the drive.

After some web searching, I found that the drive needs to be formatted using a Master Boot Record scheme, but Disk Utility was not displaying this option when formatting a drive.

How can I format a USB drive for an Elegoo Mars using macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk Utility can be used to format the drive, but first, you'll need to change the view settings to enable the Scheme options when erasing the drive.

In Disk Utility, from the View menu, select **Show All Devices**:

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility's View menu with 'Show All Devices' selected]

Next, you'll need to select the parent device on the left-hand pane, and **not** the volume:

[image: Screenshot in Disk Utility with the device selected not the volume]

Finally, after using the **Erase** button in the top bar of the window, you'll now have the option to select the scheme:

[image: Screenshot of the dialog box showing the erase options]

Erase the drive using the **MS-DOS (FAT)** format and **Master Boot Record** scheme. The name of the drive likely doesn't matter. Using these settings, I was able to copy some files back to the newly-erased drive and the printer immediately found the files and was able to begin printing again.